# Search for data that meets multiple criteria

Tags: plsql

Trying to extract people in a database that meet a certain criteria. They need to have either x & y, x & z, or x & w.

I've tried using 'in', and 'or' but I'm getting errors, or bad results (some only showing x, not two of the factors)

```
select*

from
part pa

where
pa.code in ('x', 'y') or 
pa.code in ('x', 'z') or
pa.code in ('x', 'w')
```

I'm getting a list of everyone it seems, lots only have the code of X, not X & one of the other factors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
SQL> with part (name, code) as
  2    (select 'Mike', 'x' from dual union all   -- Mike is OK, has X and Y
  3     select 'Mike', 'y' from dual union all
  4     select 'Mike', 'a' from dual union all
  5     --
  6     select 'Rita', 'a' from dual union all   -- Rita is not OK, has only X
  7     select 'Rita', 'x' from dual union all
  8     --
  9     select 'John', 'x' from dual union all   -- John is OK, has X and W
 10     select 'John', 'w' from dual union all
 11     --
 12     select 'Anna', 'z' from dual             -- Anna is not OK, has only Z
 13    )
 14  select name
 15  From part
 16  where code in ('x', 'y', 'z', 'w')
 17  group by name
 18  having count(*) = 2;

NAME
----
John
Mike

SQL>
```

Answer (score 1):

An Alternative to @Littlefoot. It uses EXISTS for instead of group and having clauses. I added a couple additional tests: Judy with all 'w', 'x', and 'y' and Peter which is missing x. The queries differ depending on whether these qualifiy or disqualify.

```
with part (name, code) as
     ( select 'Mike', 'x' from dual union all   -- Mike is OK, has X and Y
       select 'Mike', 'y' from dual union all
       select 'Mike', 'a' from dual union all
       --
       select 'Rita', 'a' from dual union all   -- Rita is not OK, has only X
       select 'Rita', 'x' from dual union all
              --
       select 'Judy', 'x' from dual union all   -- Judy is OK, has W, X and Y
       select 'Judy', 'y' from dual union all
       select 'Judy', 'w' from dual union all  
       --  
       select 'Peter', 'y' from dual union all   --Peter is not OK, does not have X 
       select 'Peter', 'w' from dual union all  
       --
       select 'John', 'x' from dual union all    -- John is OK, has X and W
       select 'John', 'w' from dual union all
       --
       select 'Anna', 'z' from dual             -- Anna is not OK, has only Z

     )
select p1.name 
  from part p1
 where 1=1
   and p1.code = 'x'
   and exists (select null 
                from part p2
               where 1=1
                 and p2.name = p1.name
                 and p2.code in ('y', 'z', 'w')
             );
```

Comment: is there a way to search without using specific people? There will be more than one or two thousand results, and I don't want to enter in that much data if there is a work around.

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding the purpose of the CTE. In this situation it's used strictly as a test data generator in order to validate the actual query. In a functional query you would remove the CTE and replace "part" with the actual table name. That table would probably contain other columns like an ID.  Since you didn't provide that information, giving only name and code, we were forced into using name. There is no search on specific names; it just a discriminator used for comparison and grouping.

Comment: Thank you @Belayer. In this table (the part table) I do have an ID which is different for every person. and there is also a participant code, which each person may have one or up to 3 or 4. These participant codes are for various groups to which the person belongs. I want to only find people who are part of more than 1 group. I'm not sure I understand how to remove the CTE and replace part with the actual table name, because the table name is part (for participants). Thanks for your help with this.

Comment: Table name is "part". I must have missed that in reading original question, sorry about that. So just delete the CTE itself. Also replace column name with ID.